# Creating NSArray of repeated numbers

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I want to initialize NSArray with given numbers of zeros. I need it to create an array of counters and in the end of the function return an index of the counter with highest value.

So the question is how to initialize NSArray of zeros of given length? Is there a good way to do it in 1-2 lines? Maybe there is a better way to count objects? How would you do it?

Thanks!

UPD: Here is the code of my existing function. It returns the maximum number of cards, which have the same rank.

```
+ (int)ranksMatched:(NSArray *)cards
{
    NSMutableArray *ranksCounter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[PlayingCard maxRank]];
    for (int i = 0; i < [PlayingCard maxRank]; ++i) {
        [ranksCounter addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    }
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (PlayingCard *card in cards) {
        int currentCount = [ranksCounter[card.rank] intValue] + 1;
        if (maxCount < currentCount) {
            maxCount = currentCount;
            maxIndex = card.rank;
        }
    }
    return maxCount;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at using `NSCountedSet`?

Comment: It's as easy as `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]; for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) [array addObject: @0];`, but I'm sure there's some better way to do what you're wanting. Can you explain the "array of counters" better? I'm not clear on what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want the group the cards by rank and return the rank of the largest group:

```
+ (int)ranksMatched:(NSArray *)cards
{
    NSCountedSet *ranks = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:[cards valueForKeyPath:@"rank"]];

    NSNumber *maxRank = nil;
    NSUInteger maxCount = 0;

    for (NSNumber *rank in ranks) {
        NSUInteger rankCount = [ranks countForObject:rank];
        if (rankCount > maxCount) {
            maxRank = rank;
            maxCount = rankCount;
        }
    }

    return [maxRank intValue];
}
```

assuming you have

```
@interface PlayingCard : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int rank;

…

@end
```

And `cards`is an array of `PlayingCard`.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I need. I was sure that there is some kind of tricky code like this. :)

Comment: Could you explain what does `[cards valueForKeyPath:@"rank"]` do? I've never seen this construction before...

Comment: For `@[hearts9, spades2, spades9, clubs7, hearts7]` it will return `@[9, 2, 9, 7, 7]`. Is it correct?

Comment: @DaZzz: Yes, it's [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-178726)